# Vue.js: Use aria-controls with conditional rendering in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, accessibility, vuex

I have two buttons which toggle some additional information on screen.
I added the buttons the `aria-controls` attribute und I render an `id` for the infobox.

Now I still get an error, when I validate the html, because I show this infobox only if a variable in the vuex store is `true`.
I render it with `v-if`.

So that means if the button was not clicked the element is not in the DOM and therefore the corresponding `id` is missing and I get an error.

I tried to use `v-show` because this would only hide it.

But this would still only render one infobox instead of 2.

Is the only way to get this right to make two infoboxes in the template and add the `v-show` to both? Or is there a nicer way to use `aria-controls`.

Thanks for any help

Best

m

---

Edit:

These are my buttons which have aria-controls.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-if="nav.items">
      <li
        v-for="(item, key) in nav.items"
        @keyup.esc="closeInfoBox">
          <button to="" aria-controls="item.name" aria-expanded="false">Designathon</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is my infobox component:

```
<template>
  <div class="Infobox" v-if="infoboxOpen" id="//should correspond to aria controls">
    <span v-html="infoContent">Some content</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which is only shown if infoboxOpen === true (from vuex store) and the content is replaced depending on which of the buttons is pressed.
(I left out some of this stuff, to make the code easier to understand and to focus on my question here).

This is where I could replace the `v-if` with the `v-show` but that would still render only one content. And I would like to have it as dynamic as possible, because users can add more infoboxes in the backend...

Hope this helps understanding my issue.

Comment: Show the code. It is near impossible to understand it via a textual description only.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there, just make `aria-controls` a dynamic attribute using
`:aria-controls="infoboxOpen ? item.name : ''"`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-if="nav.items">
      <li
        v-for="(item, key) in nav.items"
        @keyup.esc="closeInfoBox">
          <button to="" :aria-controls="infoboxOpen ? item.name : ''" aria-expanded="false">Designathon</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hm alright. That seems to be alright. But does this not hinder the ARIA part? I mean, without it being open I don't have any information, that this button does control any aria element.
Maybe I don't understand enough about aria-controls and when they are used, but ... yeah. Do you know?

Comment: That is a valid question but I'm not the person who can answer it.

Comment: `aria-controls` is a relationship attribute and should the same as the id attribute as the element as it 'controls'. The `aria-expanded` attribute should be dynamic, and be set to true or false depending on if the toggle element is 'expanded'.