# Using Accordion Bootstrap 4 in Vuejs doesn't work when hide, aria-expanded value is persistent

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I tried to use bootstrap 4 accordion in my `Vue.js` project, When I implement it, my code can normally show the animation when collapsing, but I don't know why, it doesn't happen when I try to hide it in `Vue.js`, when I check the element it seems the `aria-expanded` persistent with `true` value and doesn't change to `false`, but when I'm doing in pure HTML & CSS, there is no error in there and accordion work normally, how can I fix this?

This is my Template in Pure HTML CSS:

```css
.accordion-section-modal .accordion .card{
  margin: 16px auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--white);
  background: var(--white);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

.accordion-section-modal .accordion .card-header{
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-bottom: none;
}

.accordion-section-modal .border-top {
  border-top: solid 2px var(--light-grey);
}

.accordion-section-modal .all-course-btn {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.accordion-section-modal .accordion-logo {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>
<body>

<section class="accordion-section-modal" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title pb-3">
            <p class="coupon-modal-text">
            <strong>Choose</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
            lorem ipsum sik asik course ini orem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseOne"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            id="couponSekolah"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input text..."
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            Click me
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseTwo"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input-text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input-text"
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            click me
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseThree"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseThree"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseThree"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input-text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input-text"
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            Click Me!
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>


    <!-- Boostrap Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In `Vue.js` I just put it normally like this:

```
<template>
<section class="accordion-section-modal" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title pb-3">
            <p class="coupon-modal-text">
            <strong>Choose</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
            lorem ipsum sik asik course ini orem ipsum dolor
            sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseOne"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            id="couponSekolah"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input text..."
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            Click me
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseTwo"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input-text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input-text"
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            click me
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <div
                    class="row d-flex align-items-center accordion-status"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseThree"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseThree"
                    style="cursor: pointer;"
                >
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <span
                        ><img
                        class="accordion-logo"
                        src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/301-3019526_mage-icon-icon.png"
                        alt="logo-mitra"
                    /></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button
                        class="btn btn-link"
                        type="button"
                        style="color: var(--dark-slategrey); text-decoration: none;"
                        >
                        Type 3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div
                id="collapseThree"
                class="collapse"
                aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                data-parent="#accordionExample"
                >
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                    <p class="border-top">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>input-text</p>
                    <div class="card-text my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control coupon-input"
                            placeholder="input-text"
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 pr-0">
                        <button
                            class="all-course-btn payment-status"
                            disabled
                            style="margin-top: 24px;"
                        >
                            Click Me
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

</template>
```

When I input it in my `Vue.js` project, the accordion can collapse normally (show) but, it can't be hide, when I check it, it seems `aria-expanded: true` is persistent.

I find some article that relate to this:

1. [vue-js-use-aria-controls-with-conditional-rendering-in-vue-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849056/vue-js-use-aria-controls-with-conditional-rendering-in-vue-js)
2. [how-to-make-bootstrap4-collapse-work-in-vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766932/how-to-make-bootstrap4-collapse-work-in-vue)

2 article above is the most likely near my expectation, but somehow I can't seem implement it correctly, can someone help me to solve this problem?

**Notes:**
Just for information, I already add the jquery & bootstrap in index.html file

**EDIT 1:**

You can ignore this function `paymentAccordionChangeIcon()`, since I only use it to change my accordion card icon

**EDIT 2:**

This is my `package.json`, if you wonder what it looks like in mine:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "core-js": "^3.4.4",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "single-spa-vue": "^1.5.2",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
        "systemjs-webpack-interop": "^1.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
        "vuex": "^3.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
        "prettier": "^1.19.1",
        "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
```

Comment: just try once by giving id (same as the accordion id) to the items upon which accordion opens

Comment: @Dcoder Thankyou for your response, I think I already give the id such as `collapseOne`, `collapseTwo`, and `collapseThree` in my code

Comment: Oops sorry, I think I will delete the function first, since I only use it for icon change in my accordion card

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap-Vue or the normal Bootstrap JavaScript import?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Thankyou  for your response, I use normal bootstrap javascript import, in index.html